# Картинка поверх Input

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте! Мне нужно сделать смайлик поверх Input'а, он в формате png. Как можно это реализовать? Благодарен за любую помощь!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чего в `png`? Почему не `svg`?

Comment: Можно и в SVG, суть вопроса не в этом c:

Comment: Судя по всему, это не просто картинка, это кнопка, которая будет вызывать какое-то действие.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko Да, верно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью абсолютного позиционирования:

```css
input {
  border: 1px black solid;
  height: 31px;
  padding: 4px 40px 4px 4px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 4px 0 0 -37px;
}
```

```html
<input>
<img src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4284dcaa7857f5035883f7f50b1f48cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'>
```

Comment: Может еще понадобится обертка с position: relative;

Comment: @shugich а возможно и нет)